# How to access Typescript module-level functions from within a jQuery event handler (without giving up the "normal" this)

Tags: jquery, typescript

Please forgive the wording, I wasn't quite sure how to word it (this also made it rather difficult to google for a solution).

Now, supposing the following Typescript:

```
module Foo {
    function Bar(elem: JQuery) {
        // Do something here.
    }

    function AddEventHandlers(): void {
        $(".className").click(function () {
            this.Bar($(this));  // I would like one of these 'this' to be not like the other.
        });
    }
}
```

What is the best way to accomplish this. I can think of two options myself (and these may have their own problems, please point them out if so), neither of which I particularly like:

```
$(".className").click((e) => {
    this.Bar($(e.currentTarget));  // Not sure if currentTarget will always be the right element?
});
```

Or:

```
var _this = this;
$(".className").click(function () {
    _this.Bar($(this));
});
```

Are these the only semi-decent ways to do this, or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance for the help! :).

EDIT: My first thought was actually that the following would have been acceptable:

```
$(".className").click(function () {
    Foo.Bar($(this));
});
```

But Typescript doesn't like that :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a `module` and not a `class` the following should suffice:

```
$(".className").click(function () {
    Bar($(this));
});
```

TypeScript automatically associates `Bar` with the closest scope (`module Foo`)

Comment: I thought that I tried that, but apparently not, haha :). Thanks!